# Unserialize PHP string with obsolete MongoId and MongoDate Objects

Tags: php, mongoid, mongodate

I have this string in database.
I need to unserialize it with php.
The problem is that it returns some "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name" Objects.

I know that this string was serialized with old MongoDB PHP extension and I  try to unserialized with newer MongoDB extension.

So MongoId and MongoDate are obsolete.

This is the string:

```
$string = 'a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:52:"----------------------------------------------------";s:6:"amount";s:5:"53.09";s:10:"service_id";s:24:"------------------------";}i:1;a:6:{s:2:"id";C:7:"MongoId":24:{5b2276372a4ef288038b45ba}s:4:"name";s:21:"---------------------";s:4:"type";s:8:"one time";s:10:"service_id";s:20:"thisrhietingcfffffff";s:6:"amount";s:6:"139.29";s:10:"added_date";O:9:"MongoDate":2:{s:3:"sec";i:1528985143;s:4:"usec";i:917000;}}}';
```

When I do:

```
$result =  @unserialize($string);
var_dump($result);
```

The result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(52) "----------------------------------------------------"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(5) "53.09"
    ["service_id"]=>
    string(24) "------------------------"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (1) {
      ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
      string(7) "MongoId"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "---------------------"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "one time"
    ["service_id"]=>
    string(20) "thisrhietingcfffffff"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(6) "139.29"
    ["added_date"]=>
    object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (3) {
      ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
      string(9) "MongoDate"
      ["sec"]=>
      int(1528985143)
      ["usec"]=>
      int(917000)
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to class_alias MongoId to ObjectId. No working.
I Have tried to create new class MongoId to extend ObjectId. I am not allowed because ObjectId is a final class.

I have tried to replace C:7:"MongoId" with C:8:"ObjectID".

Still same result: __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name

Maybe a posibility is to return result like an array not an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach points in the right direction for MongoDate, because it uses normal O-type serialization. For MongoId it is more difficult since it has custom C-type serialize handlers.

If this was my task I would roughly start like this:

- Declare a class `MongoId` and implement the Serializable interface. For the `unserialize` function try and mimic the original function (available [here on L407->L220](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy/blob/d4ce6992164893d185e9d1538c48857479d1554e/types/id.c)).
- For the `serialize` function find out what `ObjectId` serialization looks like and mimic it. (Available [here L187](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/src/BSON/ObjectId.c))
- unserialize the string from the database, and serialize it again.
- Replace C:7:"MongoId" with C:21:"MongoDb\BSON\ObjectID" in the re-serialized string. You need the namespace along with the class name.
- unserialize again and pray.

The MongoId class should look something like this; but the code is not tested at all:

```
class MongoId implements Serializable {
  public $id;
  public function serialize() {
    return serialize(['oid' => $this->id]);
  }
  public function unserialize($str) {
    $this->id = $str;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps a little at least.

Comment: Thanks. You have a typo $this-id should be $this->id. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs it might be easier to just define the classes.  Then it will `unserialize` just fine.  This unserializes the value of the object that implemented `Serializable` denoted by the `C` in `C:7:"MongoId"` as `id` in the unserialized object:

```
class MongoId implements Serializable { 
    public function unserialize($str) {
        $this->id = $str; 
    }
    public function serialize() {}
}
class MongoDate {}
```

Comment: If I define classes as stated, a warning is thrown: Class MongoID has no unserializer. In your output ObjectID should be 5b2276372a4ef288038b45ba. None is shown.

Comment: I forgot @ silencer in front of serialize function.

Comment: You should be able to add `public function __wakeup() {}` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Adding public function __wakeup() or public function unserialize() {} still yields Class MongoId has no unserializer. It appears that MongoDate does not need unserializer. It works just fine if class MongoDate {} is defined.